# How to install NXT Firmware 1.28?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

Lego is giving 1.31 from their website but I need 1.28, how can I install it?

Comment: Why do you need v1.28?

Comment: @DavidLechner I borrowed a brick with 1.28 on and I have to give it back with the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, found it on my computer, [click to download from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ROr5m0F81xQldEUmxnNV9YSjg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: 2022: I’ll update the link soon, stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Enhanced Firmware](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/firmware.html) included with BricxCC is based on v1.28. You can find a download for the firmware there and download it using NXT-G or you can install BricxCC and install it via the IDE.

Comment: I dont want any enhancements only plain normal 1.28?